# Matlab vector times cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector `x = [1 2 3]` and a 3 by 3 cell array `C` that consists of N by N matrices. E.g. `C{1,1}` is an N by N matrix.

I want to multiply `x` and `C` and get a cell array `D` of size 1 by 3:

```
D{1,1} = x(1)C{1,1) + x(2)C{2,1} + x(3)C{3,1} 
D{1,2} = x(1)C{1,2) + x(2)C{2,2} + x(3)C{3,2} 
D{1,3} = x(1)C{1,3) + x(2)C{2,3} + x(3)C{3,3}
```

Comment: Honestly, your data is begging to be stored in matrices rather than cell arrays.

Answer (score 3):

### No unrolled loops

For a vector `x` of length `M=3`, and an `M-by-M` cell array `C`, the idea is to form an `M*N-by-M` matrix, where column `i` is composed of all the values in the cells `C{i,:}`. Then you can use matrix multiplication with `x.'` to get the values in `D`, and `mat2cell` to break up the result into a new cell array.

```
Ct = C';
Dvals = reshape([Ct{:}],[],M)*x.';
D = mat2cell(reshape(Dvals,N,[]),N,N*ones(M,1))
```

Test Data:

```
N = 4; M = 3; x = 1:M;
C = mat2cell(rand(N*M,N*M),N*ones(M,1),N*ones(M,1));
```

Note: This requires that each sub-matrix is the same size, as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

### With no loops:

```
D = cell(1, 3);
D{1} = x(1) * C{1,1} + x(2) * C{2,1} + x(3) * C{3,1};
D{2} = x(1) * C{1,2} + x(2) * C{2,2} + x(3) * C{3,2};
D{3} = x(1) * C{1,3} + x(2) * C{2,3} + x(3) * C{3,3};
```

### With one loop:

```
D = cell(1, 3);
for i=1:3
    D{i} = x(1) * C{1,i} + x(2) * C{2,i} + x(3) * C{3,i};
end
```

### With two loops:

```
D = cell(1, 3);
for i=1:3
    D{i} = x(1) * C{1,i};
    for j=2:3
        D{i} = D{i} + x(j) * C{j,i};
    end
end
```

Comment: "no loops" doesn't really automate the calculation, does it?

Comment: Well, the OP didn't ask for automation, did (s)he? ;)

Comment: In that case you could multiply everything by hand and just feed in the results, right? You should know better :)